# How to open mysql client?

Tags: php

Recently i installed php5 and mysql server on my freya . How can i open mysql client. I used following command to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

Any help. Is it necessary to install any client separately?

Comment: I am not sure.  How to install phpmyadmin in it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install phpMyAdmin, follow this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Will you please edit and content of the link. link only answers are highly discouraged in SE, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you have just installed the mysql server for client tools you could use the command line tools which are in **mysql-client** package and **mysql workbench** for GUI, you can install both packages like this **sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-workbench**.